# How to pass a struct to a function in a yacc file?

Tags: c, parsing, yacc

I have this in my yacc file.

```
var_declaration : type_specifier ID ';' {$2->args = ""; $2->value = 0; $2->arraysize = 0; $2->type = "variable";}
```

Everything above works.

I want to add this to it.

```
fn($2);
```

From inside the function, I want to do stuff like this.

```
 fn(struct symtab sp)
    {
    sp->value = 0;
    }
```

But when I try to compile the program I get this error:

> error: invalid type argument of ‘->’
>   (have ‘struct symtab')

Comment: Can you show the example of the code that's not working?  yacc should just emit the stuff in the braces as code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess your function should be

```
fn(struct symtab* sp)
```

instead of

```
fn(struct symtab sp)
```

and by the way, as $2 is a **union** I don't think that

```
$2->args = ""; $2->value = 0; $2->arraysize = 0;
```

is correct.
And

```
$2->type = "variable";
```

is not valid.